# SharePoint 2013 with ADFS 3.0 Server 2012 R2

Tags: 2013, adfs

I've been trying to get ADFS 3.0 on Server 2012 R2 working with SharePoint 2013.
I followed http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh305235.aspx exactly, from start to finish, but I'm running into "invalid username/password" when I attempt to login. I've added the SAML users into SharePoint.

I haven't been able to find any documentation on it, and considering it's brand new server software, I'm not too surprised. Has anyone else had any luck with it?

Answer (score 5):

This may not be the exact answer you are looking for, but it may simplify your process.  With Windows Server 2012 R2 you can use the new Web Application Proxy.  It is basically a proxy for your ADFS and SharePoint servers (which is useful when exposing outside the network).  You can setup SharePoint with normal NTLM or Kerberos authentication.  When clients access SP through the WAP, they will authenticate with ADFS and the credentials get passed to SP.  See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn280944.aspx for some more info on the WAP.